# I want to prove a series converges absolutely

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

I want to show that:
$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \cfrac{n^2 + \cos(n)}{e^{n^3}}$ converges absolutely.

Now, here is what I have done: 
$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \cfrac{n^2 + \cos(n)}{e^{n^3}} \leq \cfrac{n^2 + n^2}{e^{n^3}} = \cfrac{2n^2}{e^{n^3}}$

Now here I was told by a friend to use the integral test, but I have no idea how to apply this. Advice please, and then I will post up my attempt. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a positive series $\sum\limits_1^{\infty} a_n$ with non-increasing terms (so $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots$), its convergence is equivalent to the existence of the integral $\int_1^{\infty} f(x) dx$, where $f(x)$ is a non-increasing function with $f(n) = a_n,\ \forall n = 1, 2, \ldots$.

Comment: So if you want to test the convergence of $\dfrac{2n^2}{e^{n^3}}$, for example, note that it's non-increasing (at least for $n \ge 1$), and let $f(x) = \dfrac{2x^2}{e^{x^3}}$ which is also non-increasing (again, at least for $x \ge 1$). What is $\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{2x^2}{e^{x^3}}dx$?

Comment: @M.Vinay It equals $\frac1{3e}$? Hence it converges?

Comment: (You missed a $2$ but that's irrelevant). Yes, as the integral exists, the series is convergent. The ratio test really is simpler though. See Najib Idrissi's answer.

Comment: @M.Vinay oh $\frac2{3e}$ I see. Does this only show convergence and not absolute convergence? Do I need to take it from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ for absolute?

Comment: It's only applicable to positive series, so there's no question of conditional convergence. But you were originally testing the convergence of $\sum \frac{n^2 + \cos n}{e^{n^3}}$, and all you've done so far is show, by comparison test, that it is convergent. You still have to prove that it (the original series) is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio test is much simpler to use here. You have $$n \leq n^3 \implies e^{-n^3} \leq e^{-n}.$$ Now apply the ratio test to $\dfrac{2n^2}{e^n}$ to get the answer (the ratio converges to $e^{-1} < 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Your friend's hint is to compute $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{2x^2}{e^{x^3}} \, dx$, which can be solved using the substitution $u = x^3$.